# Turn off wps on android

Tags: android, sony-xperia, hotspot, wps

I would like to raise the level of my security. Often, I use my **Sony E2303** like a wifi hotspot, but I don't know how to **turn off WPS** pin implementation.

**Android 5.0 lolipop (root)**
patch level secured:2015-11-01
Compilation: 26.1.A.3.111.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by turn on Invisible Mode (BSSID) after  the first connection to my hotspot. (next will be automaticly if you use auto-connect Network settings in your PC, or if you know BSSID you still can connect from your terminal).This is in Tethering/Hotspot settings on your android smartfon.